# Dockerfile Quotations in --build-arg

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I've trouble passing a build-arg with single quotes `'`into `docker build`.

My `Dockerfile` looks similar to this:

```
ARG BUILD_PARAMETERS

FROM golang AS buildcontainer

RUN cd /src && go build ${BUILD_PARAMETERS}
```

I run `docker build` like this:

```
docker build --build-arg BUILD_PARAMETERS="-gcflags='all=-N -l'" . --no-cache
```

I've also tried:

```
BUILD_PARAMETERS='-gcflags='"'"'all=-N -l'"'"
```

I'm allways ending in:

```
 > [buildcontainer 21/22] RUN cd /src && go build -gcflags='all=-N -l':
...
flag provided but not defined: -l
usage: go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.
```

So the `'` quotes around `'all=-N -l'` seem to get lost. How do I escape these properly?

Edit: Tried in `zsh` and `bash`

Comment: this has nothing to do with dockerfile or go, but with how your shell parses your command-line arguments and un-wraps quotes

Comment: I tried it in bash and zsh, you might be right and it could also be dependent on what shell is used inside the container. But never the less I think the docker tags on this questions are appropriate. Since the `docker build` output suggests it is past correctly, see the updated question.

Comment: I can confirm that when I do `echo -e ${variable}` and the `variable` contains single quotes those are printed, while when I do `docker exec ${container} bash -c 'echo -e "'${variable}'"'` then I get the same output but with single quotes being removed. I can not say if that is a "bug/feature" of docker itself or of the `bash` inside my container or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ variable="a'b'c"
$ echo $variable
a'b'c
$ echo "echo '$variable'"
echo 'a'b'c'
$ bash -c "echo '$variable'"
abc
```

So its not docker but bash that eats the quotes